# Uploading app using open source SQLCipher for iOS to the app store for review

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, sqlcipher

I've implemented my app using open source SQLCipher following link

https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/

According to the instruction on the website

> All applications that make use of cryptography, including those that use SQLCipher or iOS internal libraries like CommonCrypto and Keychain, must provide documentation to Apple that demonstrates review by the Department of Commerce (DOC) Bureau of Industry and Security (BIS) and classification of the application a mass market encryption item.

Information on the PBKDF2 key derivation function is available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2

What above means?

Is there an additional configuration I have to do before upload for review or I have to submit some documentations?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Export requirements are placed on applications that include cryptography.  We have put together some guidance on the export requirements as they relate to using SQLCipher [here](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/export-requirements-for-applications-using-sqlcipher/47) in your application.

Comment: As far as I know, Implementing open source SQLCipher for iOS would be a self-classify WITHOUT an encryption registration?

I'm I right? What should I do next?